# WooCommerce: How to update order quantities at checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, product-quantity

I am trying to update order quantities at the checkout or when the order has been placed.

I can add custom meta with the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
   update_post_meta( $order_id, 'My Field', sanitize_text_field( 'testdata' ) );
}
```

How can I target a specific products quantity meta?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to just use `WC_Cart class`:

- First try to get a cart: `WC()->cart` or `WC()->instance()->cart`
- Then use method `set_quantity( $cart_item_key, $quantity)`.
  **Important:** `$cart_item_key` is not a product id, but an id in cart.
- Check `print_r` or `var_dump WC()->cart` to understand.

Comment: Hi, i only want to update the quantity once the order has been placed. WC()->cart is not available then, as the cart is empty.